# generate random numbers within a range with different probabilities

Tags: algorithm, math, random, probability

How can i generate a random number between A = 1 and B = 10 where each number has a different probability?

Example: number / probability

1 - 20%

2 - 20%

3 - 10%

4 - 5%

5  - 5%

...and so on.

I'm aware of some hard-coded workarounds which unfortunately are of no use with larger ranges, for example A = 1000 and B = 100000.

Assume we have a

```
    Rand()
```

method which returns a random number R, 0 < R < 1, can anyone post a code sample with a proper way of doing this ? prefferable in c# / java / actionscript.

Comment: Can you describe how you plan to specify the probabilities associated with the 99001 values in the range [1000, 100000]? Just to get an idea of what your expectations are. Also, what are your storage and time constraints?

Answer (score 8):

Build an array of 100 integers and populate it with 20 1's, 20 2's, 10 3's, 5 4's, 5 5's, etc. Then just randomly pick an item from the array.

```
int[] numbers = new int[100];
// populate the first 20 with the value '1'
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    numbers[i] = 1;
}
// populate the rest of the array as desired.

// To get an item:
// Since your Rand() function returns 0 < R < 1
int ix = (int)(Rand() * 100);
int num = numbers[ix];
```

This works well if the number of items is reasonably small and your precision isn't too strict. That is, if you wanted 4.375% 7's, then you'd need a much larger array.

Answer (score 5):

There is an elegant algorithm attributed by Knuth to A. J. Walker (Electronics Letters 10, 8 (1974), 127-128; ACM Trans. Math Software 3 (1977), 253-256).

The idea is that if you have a total of k * n balls of n different colors, then it is possible to distribute the balls in n containers such that container no. i contains balls of color i and at most one other color. The proof is by induction on n. For the induction step pick the color with the least number of balls.

In your example n = 10. Multiply the probabilities with a suitable m such that they are all integers. So, maybe m = 100 and you have 20 balls of color 0, 20 balls of color 1, 10 balls of color 2, 5 balls of color 3, etc. So, k = 10.

Now generate a table of dimension n with each entry being a probability (the ration of balls of color i vs the other color) and the other color.

To generate a random ball, generate a random floating-point number r in the range [0, n). Let i be the integer part (floor of r) and x the excess (r – i).

```
if (x < table[i].probability) output i
else output table[i].other
```

The algorithm has the advantage that for each random ball you only make a single comparison.

Let me work out an example (same as Knuth).

Consider simulating throwing a pair of dice.

So P(2) = 1/36, P(3) = 2/36, P(4) = 3/36, P(5) = 4/36, P(6) = 5/36, P(7) = 6/36, P(8) = 5/36, P(9) = 4/36, P(10) = 3/36, P(11) = 2/36, P(12) = 1/36.

Multiply by 36 * 11 to get 393 balls, 11 of color 2, 22 of color 3, 33 of color 4, …, 11 of color 12.
We have k = 393 / 11 = 36.

Table[2] = (11/36, color 4)

Table[12] = (11/36, color 10)

Table[3] = (22/36, color 5)

Table[11] = (22/36, color 5)

Table[4] = (8/36, color 9)

Table[10] = (8/36, color 6)

Table[5] = (16/36, color 6)

Table[9] = (16/36, color 8)

Table[6] = (7/36, color 8)

Table[8] = (6/36, color 7)

Table[7] = (36/36, color 7)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a function `p(n)` that gives you the desired probability for a random number:

```
r = rand()  // a random number between 0 and 1
for i in A to B do
    if r < p(i) 
      return i
    r = r - p(i)    
done
```

A faster way is to create an array of (B - A) * 100 elements and populate it with numbers from A to B such that the ratio of the number of each item occurs in the array to the size of the array is its probability. You can then generate a uniform random number to get an index to the array and directly access the array to get your random number.

Comment: You probably mean `if r > p(i)`. But this isn't correct. If 1 and 2 both appear with 20% percent probability, you'll always return just one of them and never the other.

Comment: in fact for 0.2 < r < 0.4 you will get 2.

Answer (score 1):

Map your uniform random results to the required outputs according to the probabilities.

E.g., for your example:

```
If `0 <= Round() <= 0.2`: result = 1.
If `0.2 < Round() <= 0.4`: result = 2.
If `0.4 < Round() <= 0.5`: result = 3.
If `0.5 < Round() <= 0.55`: result = 4.
If `0.55 < Round() <= 0.65`: result = 5.
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of [Knuth's Algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/random-number-generator-in-arbitrary-probability-distribution-fashion/). As discussed by some of the answers it works by 
1) creating a table of summed frequencies 
2) generates a random integer 
3) rounds it with ceiling function
4) finds the "summed" range within which the random number falls and outputs original array entity based on it

Answer (score 0):

**Inverse Transform**

In probability speak, a cumulative distribution function F(x) returns the probability that any randomly drawn value, call it X, is <= some given value x. For instance, if I did F(4) in this case, I would get .6. because the running sum of probabilities in your example is `{.2, .4, .5, .55, .6, .65, ....}`. I.e. the probability of randomly getting a value less than or equal to 4 is .6.   However, what I actually want to know is the *inverse* of the cumulative probability function, call it F_inv.  I want to know what is the x value given the cumulative probability. I want to pass in F_inv(.6) and get back 4.  That is why this is called the inverse transform method.

So, in the inverse transform method, we are basically trying to find the interval in the cumulative distribution in which a random Uniform (0,1) number falls.  This works out to the algorithm that perreal and icepack posted.  Here is another way to state it in terms of the cumulative distribution function

```
Generate a random number U
for x in A .. B
   if U <= F(x) then return x
```

Note that it might be more efficient to have the loop go from B to A and check if U >= F(x) if the smaller probabilities come at the beginning of the distribution

Answer (score 0):

Considering, say, the random number range of `1, 2, 3` with the probabilities of `50%, 30% and 20%`, I think it is the easiest to think about the problem as suggested by Jim Mischel's answer:

`"Build an array of 100 integers and populate it with 50 ones, 30 twos and 20 threes. Then just randomly pick an item from the array."`

... but it is probably more efficient to implement it in terms of multiple index windows (in other words, index ranges) as opposed to array allocation and initialization:

```cpp
#include <assert.h>

#include <random>
#include <iostream>

// g++ algorithm.cpp -g -o algorithm

int main()
{
    // random number range: 1, 2, 3
    int lowest = 1;
    int highest = 3;

    // probabilities: 50%, 30%, 20%
    int probs[] = { 50, 30, 20 };

    /*

    "Build an array of 100 integers and populate it with 50 ones, 30 twos and 20 threes.
    Then just randomly pick an item from the array."

    */

    const int prob_count = sizeof(probs)/sizeof(probs[0]);

    // must have as many random number possibilities as there are probabilities
    assert(highest - lowest + 1 == prob_count);

    const int random_min = 0;
    const int random_max = 99;

    srand(time(NULL)); // seed
    const int continuous_index = random_min + rand() % ((random_max + 1) - random_min);
    
    std::cout << "continuous index: " << continuous_index << std::endl;

    int window_index = -1;

    /*

    window index 0 (50%): continuous indexes 0 - 49
    window index 1 (30%): continuous indexes 50 - 79
    window index 2 (20%): continuous indexes 80 - 99

    */

    for (int i = 0, index = 0; i < prob_count; i++)
    {
        const int prob = probs[i];
        assert(prob > 0 && prob < 100); // more likely a mistake than an intended arg

        const int continuous_index_from = index;
        const int continuous_index_to = continuous_index_from + prob - 1;

        std::cout << "window index " << i << " (" << prob << "%): continuous indexes " << continuous_index_from << " - " << continuous_index_to << std::endl;

        if (continuous_index >= continuous_index_from && continuous_index <= continuous_index_to)
        {
            window_index = i;
            // do not // break;
        }

        if (!(i + 1 < prob_count)) // the last iteration
            assert(continuous_index_to == 99); // sanity: probabilities must add up to 100

        index = continuous_index_to + 1;
    }

    assert(window_index >= 0 && window_index < prob_count);
    std::cout << "window index: " << window_index << std::endl;

    const int random = lowest + window_index;

    assert(random >= lowest && random <= highest);
    std::cout << "random number: " << random << std::endl;
}
```

Sample output:

```
continuous index: 89
window index 0 (50%): continuous indexes 0 - 49
window index 1 (30%): continuous indexes 50 - 79
window index 2 (20%): continuous indexes 80 - 99
window index: 2
random number: 3
```