# How to create a random selector by custom number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

Traditionally if I wish to choose a case occurred 25%, I use "arc4random()%" function by integer to trigger the case of 1/4 chance.
Now I have 4 cases with float rate. Let's say,

A 0.3055

B 0.391

C 0.165

D 0.1485

A+B+C+D=1

How can I develop a random selector to trigger a case of 4 by properly selecting? Of course, case B gets the most chance to be selected.

Many thanks

Comment: I posted a solution to a similar question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635448/generate-random-numbers-within-a-range-with-different-probabilities/13637027#13637027.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is perfect, but it'll get you close

```
    int probability = arc4random_uniform(10000);
    NSLog(@"Probability: %i", probability);

    if (probability < 3055) {
        // A
    }
    else if (probability <= (3055 + 3910)) {
        // B
    }
    else if (probability <= (3055 + 3910 + 1650)) {
        // C
    }
    else {
        // D
    }
```

Comment: The `391` should be `3910` and `165` should be `1650`.

Comment: +1. Just a bit of explanation: chances of `probability` in the code above will fall within a given range (e.g. `probability < 3055`, `probability <= 3055 +3910` etc) are proportional to the length of that range relative to total length (which is 10000). And the relative length of each range is given by its probability times 10000 (e.g. 3055 = 0.3055 * 10000).

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

By selecting with the appropriate probability from a uniform distribution.

```
int myOwnFunkyDistribution(void)
{
    uint32_t A = 0.3055 * UINT32_MAX;
    uint32_t B = A + 0.3910 * UINT32_MAX;
    uint32_t C = B + 0.1650 * UINT32_MAX;

    uint32_t r = arc4random();

    if (r < A)
        return 0;

    if (r < B)
        return 1;

    if (r < C)
        return 2;

    return 3;
}
```

With more cases, this is **definitely to be refactored** using an array and a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a multinomial sample. You could do this in iOS with [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Multinomial-Distribution.html) or other C- or C++-based statistics libraries.